# Django compressor tags ignored on production machine

Tags: django, django-compressor

I'm using django compressor (1.3) but it seems to be ignored on my production machine.

I've tested on my local (with `manage.py run server`), and both css and js are being amalgamated (although not minified). However on my development machine, the `{% compress %}` tags seem to be completely ignored.

My base template looks something like -

```
{% load compress %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-GB">
<head>
{% block css %}
    {% compress css %}
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='{{ STATIC_URL }}css/base.css'  media="all"/>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='{{ STATIC_URL }}css/nav.css'  media="all"/>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='{{ STATIC_URL }}css/catalog.css'  media="all"/>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='{{ STATIC_URL }}css/cart.css'  media="all"/>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='{{ STATIC_URL }}css/content.css'  media="all"/>
    {% endcompress %}
{% endblock css %}
```

`'compressor'` is listed in my installed apps setting and I've set `COMPRESS_ENABLED` to `True` (in order to test on my local machine).

I expect I'm missing something obvious but I've been searching for a while now..

UPDATE

django-compressor is installed on my production machine (using `pip install -r requirements.txt` in a virtualenv).

`DEBUG` is set to `False` and I'm using the following static files finders -

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)
```

FURTHER UPDATE

I can compress everything inline (within the html) if I add the `inline` parameter to the `{% compress %}` tag. However nothing happens when I use the `file` parameter (I'd rather use an external file that can be cached - so sticking with the inline option isn't ideal).

Comment: does `django-compressor` requires a special python package which is not installed on your production environment?

Comment: Need more info. Are you sure you are using the appropriate `settings.py` on the production server? What django and django-compressor versions are you using? `DEBUG` is set to `False` on production, right? Are you using `staticfiles` app? Thanks.

Comment: @omeinusch requirements have should be installed by pip. And certainly django-compressor has been installed.

Comment: @AidanEwen try updating django_compressor to the latest version. probably [this issue](https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor/issues/85) is relevant.